# Grep and Regex: filter subdomains in a file

Tags: command-line, grep, regex

First of all sorry I should learn some grep and regex instead of asking that question but I have a little shortage of time for now. And I am definitely going to learn egrep eventually.

**So here is the input:**

```
202.125.132.76          host    av.google.com
202.147.187.10          host    cms1web.google.com
202.147.187.10          host    cms2web.google.com
    "autodiscover.google.com
    "cms1web.google.com
    "cms2web.google.com
    "dialin.google.com
 - afghanistan.google.com
  - autodiscover.google.com
  - bangladesh.google.com
  - bdbkashonline.google.com
  - cms1web.google.com
*.google.com
*.ibank.google.com
*.ibankintl.google.com
*.itrade.google.com
202.125.133.232 403     host    autodiscover.google.com
104.40.82.191 - EnterpriseEnrollment.google.com
107.154.104.16 - iTrade.google.com
107.154.108.2 - MIS.google.com
116.71.129.169  testpaymentapi.google.com
119.159.231.12          host    av.google.com
```

**Output should be**

```
av.google.com
cms1web.google.com
cms2web.google.com
autodiscover.google.com
so on.......
```

I want only *.*google.com not any thing else in result, line by line

I don't want that Apostrophes and hyphens at all only subdomains as shown above.

Thanks if you could help me :)

Comment: I don't get what the rule is for the matches, why it does not match `MIS.google.com` or `testpaymentapi.google.com` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve such task you need to imagine clear and unequivocal logical rules. According to your example output you need to get the strings that consist of:

- three words,
- divided by two dost,
- the first word could contains letters and numbers,
- the rest two words contain only letters,
- all letters should be in lowercase.

If the above is correct you could achieve the desired output by the following cobination of the commands `sed` and `grep`:

```bsh
sed -e '/[A-Z]/d' -e '/*/d' input.txt | grep -oP '[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+'
```

Explanation:

- The first expression (`-e`) will delete `d` all lines that contain capital letters, the second one will delete all lines that contain wildcard `*`, while `sed` reading the `input.txt` file.
- The output of `sed` command is piped `|` to `grep`.
- The option `-o` of `grep` will *show only the part of a line matching PATTERN* and `-P` tells that *PATTERN is a Perl regular expression*. Within the PATTERN `[a-z0-9]+` means that we need to match a word that contains numbers or/and lowercase letters and there must have at least one character `+`; `\.` stands for a literal dot, because `.` has a meaning of any character while it is not escaped by a backslash `\`.

Example output, based on the input provided in the question (note here the output is sorted and only the unique values are printed):

```bsh
$ sed -e '/[A-Z]/d' -e '/*/d' input.txt | grep -oP '[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+' | sort -u
afghanistan.google.com
autodiscover.google.com
av.google.com
bangladesh.google.com
bdbkashonline.google.com
cms1web.google.com
cms2web.google.com
dialin.google.com
testpaymentapi.google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -Po '^[^-*"]*?\K[[:alnum:]-]+\.google\.com$' input
av.google.com
cms1web.google.com
cms2web.google.com
autodiscover.google.com
testpaymentapi.google.com
av.google.com
```

- non-greedily match and discard a sequence of characters not including `-`, `*`, or `"`

then

- match and output a sequence of alphanumeric characters and hyphens (although your input doesn't have any, they are legal in a domain name) followed by `.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+\.*[a-z]+
```

This expression select for you:
domains and sub-domains any kind.
Also recommend this website with regex testing and debugging:
[1]: https://regex101.com/